# Application to read PDF files

Tags: pdf

I have Ubuntu 22 LTS. Which PDF reader is a good one ? I see that adobe does not publish a linux version any more. Looking for something with security patches and long term support. I do not want to read it within my browser, need standalone app too. Right now Document viewer opens it, is this app okay for all PDFs, like ones with forms embedded in them ?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 22 (or the *year* product based on 22.04) is intended for *headless* operation, ie. it's a specialist server version of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  The *year* format (22) tells you it's *snap* only, where as 22.04 can use *deb* and *snap* packages (as well as *appimage*, *flatpak*, compiled from source etc). Are you sure you mean 22 & not 22.04?

Comment: Document Viewer, like most software in Ubuntu, is made by volunteers at one of many upstream projects. If you discover a feature that Document Viewer lacks, or a kind of PDF that it cannot handle well, please let that upstream project know about it by filing a bug report. All software in Ubuntu's "Main" repository comes with "*security patches and long term support*."